# Error with Python import LightGBM

Tags: python, opencv

I have installed lightGBM as described here on Linux:

https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/wiki/Installation-Guide#linux-2

I am able to successfully run the GPU training (and CPU) using the CLI:
https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/blob/master/docs/GPU-Tutorial.md#run-your-first-learning-task-on-gpu

However, when i try to import the python package (python 3.6) I receive the following error:

```
OSError: /home/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lightgbm-0.2-py3.6.egg/lightgbm/lib_lightgbm.so: symbol clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties, version OPENCL_2.0 not defined in file libOpenCL.so.1 with link time reference
```

I am pretty new to understanding linking and other things that may be the problem. Anyone able to provide some easy to follow suggestions?

Comment: Which python package are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

[LightGBM](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) now comes with a [python API](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python-API.html).

```
import numpy as np
from lightgbm import LGBMClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons


model = LGBMClassifier(boosting_type='goss', num_leaves=31, max_depth=- 1, learning_rate=0.1, n_estimators=300, device = "gpu")

train, label = make_moons(n_samples=300000, shuffle=True, noise=0.3, random_state=None)

model.fit(train, label)
```

If you managed to build it for the GPU, you are probably a couple of steps away from setting up the python interface.

Assuming the built was successful and the repertory looks like this:

```
~/Codes/LightGBM$ tree -d -L 1
.
├── build
├── compute
├── docker
├── docs
├── examples
├── helpers
├── include
├── pmml
├── python-package
├── R-package
├── src
├── swig
├── tests
└── windows
```

Simply use the following commands to set up the python API.

```
cd python-package/
sudo python setup.py install --precompile
```

Source detailed guide to [install LightGBM with GPU support](https://www.thekerneltrip.com/machine-learning/lgbmgpu/)

Answer (score 0):

To use LGBM in python you need to install a python wrapper for CLI. Maybe something like [this.](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/tree/master/python-package) Then you need to point this wrapper to the CLI. You could look up GBMClassifier/ Regressor where there is a variable called exec_path. You should set up the absolute path here.

Hopefully this helps , 
I will take an example of [this wrapper](https://github.com/ArdalanM/pyLightGBM)
Here is the example :
`

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets, metrics, model_selection
from pylightgbm.models import GBMClassifier
exec = "~/Documents/apps/LightGBM/lightgbm"
X, Y = datasets.make_classification(n_samples=200, n_features=10)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2)
clf = GBMClassifier(exec_path=exec, min_data_in_leaf=1)
clf.fit(x_train, y_train, test_data=[(x_test, y_test)])
y_pred = clf.predict(x_test)
print("Accuracy: ", metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

`

Comment: I have added the python wrapper. I am curious if you have an example with exec_path? Would that address the error?

Comment: @B_Miner Sure, I will add it in the answer.